# maven-resources-plugin overwrite output directory not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot application that serves vue static files as well. In the pom.xml I use `maven-resources-plugin` to copy the static files to resources folder. It works as intended the first time, but for some reason it does not overwrite the output directory when I change files the vue project and build the project again, even when I use `<overwrite>true</overwrite>`. When I delete the output dir manual and build again - it works fine.

My pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions> 
    <execution>
      <id> Copy vue resources </id>
      <phase> generate-resources </phase>
      <goals>
        <goal> copy-resources </goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <overwrite> true </overwrite>
        <outputDirectory> src/main/resources/public </outputDirecroty>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory> ${project.basedir}/../c4i-vue/target/dist </directory>
            <includes>
              <include>static/</include>
              <include>index.html</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also tried to put the `<overwrite>true</overwrite>` in the outside configuration but it didn’t work as well:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <overwrite> true </overwrite>
  </configuration>
  <executions> 
    <execution>
      <id> Copy vue resources </id>
      <phase> generate-resources </phase>
      <goals>
        <goal> copy-resources </goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory> src/main/resources/public </outputDirecroty>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory> ${project.basedir}/../c4i-vue/target/dist </directory>
            <includes>
              <include>static/</include>
              <include>index.html</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I would love some help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be working fine..
Maybe the files were updated but the folders still have the last update date?